# Android: listen for Switch in ActionBar

Tags: android

I am a newbie android developer, I added a `Switch` inside the `ActionBar`, but how do I listen for that `Switch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to set a listener to your switch.
I don't know how are you inserting the Switch into the ActionBar, but after you add it, you need to set a listener:

```
yourSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that before but didn't work. I inflated a layout where the `Switch` is inside with `MenuInflater`